# Does piping ls to head stop it's execution half way?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

If I run `ls folder | head` in a directory with a lot of files, the execution time is about 50 times faster than `ls folder | tail`. Does the `head` command stops `ls` from executing wholy when it has enough (10) lines?

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere because "pipe to head" gives me tons of unrelated results on Google or here.

If the answer is no, then is there a more efficient way to list only some files instead of running `ls` completely and cutting the output with `head`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once `head` has read enough lines from it's `stdin` (`stdout` of `ls`), then it exits and therefore closes the `stdin`. When that happens, the pipe is considered to be broken and `ls` receives a `SIGPIPE` signal. As a reaction to that it terminates as well, way before processing everything that it would normally do.
In the case of `tail`, it has to wait for `ls` to terminate to know which X number of lines were the last ones.

Comment: This causes a lot of confusion for people who don't expect this behavior. We'll often hear people ask "Why does my program crash/error when I pipe it to `head`?". And the answer is usually that the program assumed all its writes to `stdout` would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This would be more efficient as no new processes are created:

```
a=( folder/* )
echo ${a[@]:0:9}
```

In same cases it may be even better as you don't have to prepend `folder/` if you want to do something with the result.